# SharePoint Import/Export Command for Library with version setting disabled

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, sharepoint-library

I have to export a SharePoint library from a site in server A and import it to a library in server B such that only the items that are new or updated are imported to site in server B. While this can be done with "UpdateVersion" parameter set to "ignore" for export command, the problem is we don't have version setting enabled for source or destination library. How can I import only the updated items or new items? Enabling version setting is not an option. If its not possible using export/import is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found answer by trying.As it turns out even if you have version setting disabled for sharepoint library in source site and destination site you can import with overwrite parameter. It will update the existing item. This will work only if the "Name" field of document(in case of library) is not changed. I have also put it in detail in my blog: http://www.sp-androidgeeks.blogspot.in/2015/03/migrate-sharepoint-listlibrary.html